# Where is the mistake in this create table?

Tags: mysql, sql

this is the final table but still wrong :(

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
   message_id   INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   parent_id    INTEGER UNSIGNED   NOT NULL,
   forum_id     TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   user_id      MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   subject      VARCHAR(100)     NOT NULL,
   body         LONGTEXT         NOT NULL,
   date_entered TIMESTAMP        NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (message_id),
   FOREIGN KEY forum_id REFERENCES forums,
   FOREIGN KEY parent_id REFERENCES messages,
   FOREIGN KEY user_id REFERENCES users
);
```

The error now is that I cannot set parent_id as a FOREIGN KEY ( This is because if someone answer to a post, this post is set as a parent_id of the new reply).

Thanks

Comment: Not related to your question, but the unique contstraint on user_id means that each user can have only one message.  Was that your intent?  Also, the lack of foreign keys is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks Marty, the table is not finish, foreign keys to users and forum table are not added yet. I wanted to fix these errors first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE messages 
(
   message_id   INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   parent_id    INTEGER UNIQUE   NOT NULL,
   forum_id     TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   user_id      MEDIUMINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   subject      VARCHAR(100)     NOT NULL,
   body         LONGTEXT         NOT NULL,
   date_entered TIMESTAMP        NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
);
```

A Primary key is already a unique index. And keep the type definition together:

```
 INTEGER UNIQUE UNSIGNED
```

is not the right order of keywords.

#### Generally you can find the problematic part of your query in the MySQL error message after the word `near`.